# Misplaced elements inside the table using the reveal.js framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

Consider the following table declared as a part of a slide in the `reveal.js` library:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/theme/white.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="dist/reveal.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize({
                hash: true,
                plugins: [ ]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following result in the normal HTML (without `reveal.js` and only using the `<table>` part):

[image]

While getting this result in the `reveal.js`, I noticed some differences compared to the normal HTML output:

[image]

Actually, the library works well when using the simple text or `<p>` instead of `<div>` or `<img>`.

How can I achieve the result the same as the normal HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there is a `reset.css` file in the `reveal.js` library that contains the following rule:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
main, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

It seems that the problem is with the `vertical-align: baseline` line. So, I fixed this with the following CSS rule in my `index.html` file:

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```